# Making views work with templates generated on the server with AngularJS & Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am looking to create an application with AngularJS that also has pages rendered on the server side with PHP/Laravel.

Essentially, I want to be able to render a static version of a view on the server side, but have the Javascript views start kicking in as soon as the page is rendered.

The idea being that when a user goes to an internal page for the first time, all of the content is rendered ahead of time on the server, yet the one page application will continue to work as soon as the page is loaded in the browser.

The backend of the application is currently written in Laravel, so I would feel comfortable writing the view logic in PHP.

What would be the best direction to go for this? I really want to avoid passing the pages to a third party service such as `prerender.io` or first rendering the page in `phantomjs`.

**Essentially**: having Javascript disabled on a web browser will not make any one page AngularJS app run. This is why I want to find a way to render the *full* page  on the server, and once the page is loaded in the browser, either re-render the page (if that is the way it must be done) with my Angular application or somehow [bind all of the data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) with the static views with my AngularJS [controllers and models](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Comment: So, you want to have angular js inside your blade isn't it ? i.e., `{{ xx }}` inside blade ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen... no, I want to pre-render the full angularjs page that would be outputted on the browser from the server side. Once that is done, I want the app to continue running with Javascript.

Comment: Why you wanted to do it so ? Because of the conflicts ?

Comment: I want it so that I can build an app that can be crawled correctly by Bing... having a dynamic angular app is awesome, but it will not work correctly when people are using an app with Javascript disabled (or if an invalid JS call kills the web app).

Comment: Having Javascript disabled will never makes the app run for any reason. You really don't need to worry about crawling (if you wanted to it for ranking and SEO (I guess not only this makes you rank good). You should worry about the scope of your app while you do migrate. You can only do future migration only if you build your app in good practise recommended by larvel